# both (the) X and (the) Y

Tags: prepositions, conjunctions, definite-articles

Which of the three alternatives is correct (or recommended)?

1. "in both the military and civil fields";
2. "in both military and civil fields";
3. "in both the military and the civil fields".

(entire sentence: "Current UAV technology has led to an exponential growth in the potential applications of drones *in both (the) military and (the) civil fields*.")

[update] The intended meaning is "the military field *and* the civilian field"; the term "field" is intended as synonym of "sector".

Comment: I'd be tempted to use "civilian" rather than just "civil".

Comment: ... and I'd use 'both the military and the civilian sectors'. 'Fields' at least strongly connotes various spheres of operations within both sectors.  Possibly an implication too far (possibly not).

Comment: As the previous comment says, "both military and civil fields" suggests there are multiple military and multiple civil fields; while "both the military and the civil fields" suggests one of each. You could update the question to say what you mean.

Comment: thanks for the comments: I updated the question accordingly. What about option (1)? Is it a correct alternative to (3)?

Comment: Arthrous vs anarthrous nouns is like jackets vs jumpers - pick whichever works at the time. Linking them to a “both ___ and ___” construct is like linking the choice of clothing to the colour of your taxi. One doesn’t normally constrain the other. Eg: both this and that; both the best and the worst of times; both him and the others.

Comment: At least in STEM publishing (e.g., the Springer, Nature, Elsevier groups of journals), "both the A and B" would typically be considered to contain a parallelism error and would be edited to read "both the A and the B" (or "both A and B", as appropriate).